# TextInputLayout Dropdown menu getting Failed to instantiate one or more classes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.

Exception Details
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:247)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:216)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:144)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:114)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:476)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.(TextInputLayout.java:455)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:293)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:156)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:117)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:270)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:426)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:437)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:341)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:358)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:701)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$8(RenderTask.java:848)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:200)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:298)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

i'm trying to make a dropdown menu by following some tutorials but cannot proceed due to "Failed to instantiate one or more classes" upon putting style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu" on com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

Comment: Check that you added dependency of the Material component.

Comment: i have already added material component and updated to the latest version